# Missing dependency 'libtag1c2a' when installing Musique 1.4 on Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, 16.10

I just made a fresh install of ubuntu 16.10 (64bits) and I'm trying to reinstall some packages, including `musique` 1.4 from deb 64bits package, which worked just fine on my previous system (16.10, 64bits ), but I got a dependency error for `libtag1c2a`.

```
sudo dpkg -i musique64.deb

>> musique depends on libtag1c2a; however:
>> Package libtag1c2a is not installed
```

I tried to install `libgtag1c2a` with `apt`, it failed, package is not available.
Suggested remplacement packages  (`libtag1v5-vanilla:i386 libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla libtag1v5`) doesn't make it work either.

I found a similar topic [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/7729/7271) and the same bug is also reported in the [developer web site](http://flavio.tordini.org/musique-1-4)

[EDIT]
Solution tried:

- Install `musique` 32bits deb package
- Install `musique` 1.1 with apt, it works but it's a big regression
- Install `libtag1c2a` trusty package : conflict with `libtag1v5`
- `sudo dpkg --force-depends -i package.deb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem **solved** on a up to date `Ubuntu 16.10` (march 2017), with `musique 1.5`. Regular install worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

All right, well, since it has come to this... Try [this package](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/musique_1.4-0+yakkety1_amd64.deb) (same packaging as the official Ubuntu Yakkety package, but with 1.4 source).

For the paranoid (or those who want to build a 32 bits package), [here](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/musique_1.4-0+yakkety1.debian.tar.xz)'s the Debian source packaging; the source for Musique 1.4 is [here](https://github.com/flaviotordini/musique/archive/1.4.tar.gz).

---

The package `libtag1c2a` is available for [Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libtag1c2a) and [Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libtag1c2a); in later versions it was renamed to [`libtag1v5`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libtag1v5). Ideally, the developer should provide a Xenial+ package which depends on the latter, or at least a Debian source package so that others can build one.

In the meantime, you can try to install the Trusty `libtag1c2a` package; hovever note that since `libtag1c2a` and `libtag1v5` install the same files, you can't have both packages installed, so if you have packages which depend on `libtag1v5`, this won't work.

In that case, since you actually do have the required library, just under another package name, simply ignoring dependencies may actually work:

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends -i package.deb
```

Comment: as you said, trusty package doesn't work because of conflict with `libtag1v5`. Do you think I can safely remove libtag1v5, since it's part of the default Ubuntu installation ?

Comment: You can try to remove it; if you have any packages which depend on it, Apt will tell you what they are and ask if you want to proceed.

Comment: I did, and I'll not try it.  here is the list of dependencies : `cheese gnome-documents gnome-video-effects gstreamer1.0-plugins-good libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libtag1v5 libtagc0 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 musique phonon-backend-vlc qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
  rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins thumbnailer-service totem totem-plugins tracker tracker-extract tracker-miner-fs ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon
  unity8 unity8-common unity8-desktop-session vlc vlc-nox `

Comment: @mxdsp See my edit.

Comment: Well in fact It results on broken dependencies when I try to install anything with  `apt `, so I had to run `apt install -f` and delete `musique` package again. I'm back to  `1.3 ` with the workaround bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround, resulting in a working installation of version 1.3 instead of 1.4

- downloaded `musique_1.3-1~webupd8~xenial_amd64.deb` from [WebUpd8 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=musique&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=)
- installed with GDebi

I'm still looking for a cleaner solution, and for getting the last version to work.